# How do I fix a PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I created a table answers and added the following index to it:

```
add_index :answers, [:output, :question_id], unique: true
```

The index allows for a fast lookup of an answer by it's output and question_id. When creating many answers, I got the following error:

> PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR:  index row size 3088 exceeds maximum 2712 for index
>   "index_answers_on_output_and_question_id"
>   HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
>   Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.

How do I fix this issue? I can move the uniqueness aspect to the model, but the indexing is important. Does Rails support creating MD5 hash values?

Comment: For now, I'm just avoiding saving any records that are greater than 2700 characters.

Answer (score 2):

It's an error raised by Postgres. It's complaining that you should index md5(giant_string) or sometthing along those lines (in your case I imagine an answer_position field), as opposed to giant_string directly, because indexing strings that large is not so useful.

Answer (score 1):

Create a migration with the following code, just replace the table and field names:

```
def up
  execute <<~SQL
    CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY "index_table_on_field" ON table(MD5(field));
  SQL
end
```